# Stop Magento creating URL Rewrites for Simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, url-rewrite, simple-product

The website only shows configurable products but before the configurable product is created the simple products are created and URL Rewrites are created for the products automatically.

These simple products are not visible and do not need URL Rewrites.

If the configurable product has the same name as the simple products is will create a URL Rewrite with the ID at the end eg. product-4355.

I could create a script to empty the table and re-index but them any custom URL Rewrites will be deleted.

I have seen some similar post but they mention methods that work on magento 1.7 and wanted some advise whether anyone has had similar requests on magento 1.9

Any advice?

Comment: Is it possible to modify the core file to only URL Rewrite configurable products???

Comment: I have seen some similar post but they mention methods that work on magento 1.7 and wanted some advise whether anyone has had similar requests on magento 1.9

Comment: Second module recommendation on that post appears to work on Magento versions > 1.7. Have you tested that ?

Comment: I have just tried it and it doesnt work for any product.